# MYSQL, ORDER BY LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, search, sql-like

I have 2 tables Thread and Posts, i would like to search my posts and order by thread with most matches.

Right now i have this:

```
SELECT Threads.* 
FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN Threads ON Posts.ThreadID=Threads.ThreadID 
WHERE Posts.Content LIKE '%" . $search .  "%' 
     OR Posts.User LIKE '%" . $search ."%'
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: I believe the question is in the subject line: how would you add an ORDER BY using LIKE?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: the question is in the first line, "i would like to search my posts and order by thread with most matches"

Comment: There is no question in the title. The title is actually really rubbish, as it just lists some MySQL keywords. Please fix it to describe your _question_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a join to calculate the number of posts per thread.  Since you're not selecting any columns from Posts, that's the only join you'll need.

```
select  t.* 
from    Threads t
join    (
        select  ThreadID
        ,       count(*) as PostCount
        from    Posts
        where   p.Content LIKE '%" . $search .  "%' 
                or p.User LIKE '%" . $search ."%'
        group by
                ThreadID
        ) PostCount
on      PostCount.ThreadID = t.ThreadID
order by
        PostCount.PostCount desc
```

Comment: Aren't you counting the number of posts a thread has? I guess he would like the number of matches his LIKE-expressions gives...

Comment: @PeterG.: Makes sense, and gives a simpler solution as well with a single join, edited